# Как на php избавиться от повторений и сделать грамотную формулу

Tags: php, массивы, ооп

```
Значение 1 Значение 2        %
    5          5           57.8
    5          4           54.6
    5          3           51.5
    5          2           48.3
    5          1           47.8
    4          5           53.6
    4          4           50.4
    4          3           47.3
    4          2           44.1
    4          1           43.6
    3          5           49.4
    3          4           46.2
    3          3           43.1
    3          2           39.9
    3          1           39.4
    2          5           39.9
    2          4           36.8
    2          3           36.3
    2          2           30.5
    2          1           29.9
    1          5           15.8
    1          4           12.6
    1          3            9.5
    1          2            6.3
    1          1            5.8
```

Друзья, коллеги. Есть некая табличка. Хочется получить на выходе следующее:
Есть поле для ввода стоимости товара и ввода значения  1 и значения 2. При совпадении условия, то стоимость умножается на процент. Каким образом можно сделать эту формулу по уму? Я пока вижу только if...else, но их много будет. Заранее спасибо за грамотную мысль. Если это еще сделать на ООП PHP, то вообще цены не будет этой формуле.

Comment: С чем должно совпасть условие и какое вообще условие?

Comment: @Эникейщик, есть поле 1 в которое вводится значение 1, есть поле 2, в которое должно руками вводиться значение 2. Есть поле 3, в которое вводиться произвольное число. При совпадении значения 1 и значения 2 произвольное число умножается на процент.

Comment: Понятно. Что конкретно вызывает затруднения?

Comment: @Эникейщик, не хочется городить огород из if...else.

Comment: А где вы здесь видите огород? Тут достаточно функции из пары строк. http://www.php.su/functions/custom/?1

Comment: @Эникейщик, как? Приведите пример.

Comment: Это вы должны привести пример того, что у вас не получается, а мы уже подсказываем, как исправить ошибки. Ну и по ссылке, которую я дал в предыдущем комментарии, примеров достаточно. Но вообще решение очевидно: ``if ($znachenie1 == $znachenie2) {return $znachenie3 * $procent;}``

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо большое. Вот что получилось. Может будут замечания? https://pastebin.com/yVCiKGRA